# How to get all records that have one-to-many relationships in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have managers and projects. One manager may have many projects, but a project has only one manager (managerId in project table). What would be the best way in Hibernate to get all managers that have at least one project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a JPQL query. You can select the managers and do a join on projects with a `group by` or `distinct` to eliminate duplicates, or you could use `exists` in a subquery. I can help you with the JPQL if you show your entities and their relevant fields.